# Add custom layout to ActionBar with Gravity Left?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat

[image]

The ActionBar shows a space on the left side of the custom view.
I want to set my custom view align left of Actionbar.

I'm trying to set

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

and any other method like setLogo(null),But it's not work.

My code is like

```
    ABCMainView actionLayout = new ABCMainView(this); //my custom view
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionLayout);
```

My ActionBar is android-appcompat-v21.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in your Toolbar xml config

```
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Base on Chris Banes' response https://stackoverflow.com/a/26495926/1568429