# Unalble to align left the custom layout in app bar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat, appbar

I've been dealing with this for quite a while. No success though!
What I want is to set the custom layout to the very left of the app bar. WITH NO MARGINS whatsoever. But no matter what I change, the layout doesn't go left any further.

[image]

My styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue4main</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue5</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/blue6</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/blue3</item>
    <!---->
    <item name="android:contentInsetLeft" tools:targetApi="lollipop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetStart" tools:targetApi="lollipop">0dp</item>
```

my custom_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:background="@color/black1"
          android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
          android:layoutDirection="ltr"
          android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
          android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
          app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
          app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
   ...
```

and the code:

```
    private void insideOnCreateForVicinity() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // you can use ABS or the non-bc ActionBar
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM  |  ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP |ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vicinity_and_filtercone_search_bar, null);
    // the view that contains the search "magnifier" icon
    final ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
    final ImageView filterConeIcon = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ic_filter_cone);
    final DelayAutoCompleteTextView textViewVicinity = (DelayAutoCompleteTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_view_vicinity);
    textViewVicinity.setThreshold(3);//after how many letters users types, send the request.
    textViewVicinity.setAdapter(new VicinityAutoCompleteAdapter(this));
    textViewVicinity.setLoadingIndicator((android.widget.ProgressBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));
    textViewVicinity.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            VicinityPageItem p = (VicinityPageItem) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            textViewVicinity.setText(p.Name);
            textViewVicinity.setSelection(textViewVicinity.length());//put the cursor at the end
            searchFilter.setVicinityID(p.ID);//hamed. kesafate in
            reload(searchFilter);
        }
    });
    actionBar.setCustomView(layout);
```

I've tried links below and some others, non worked for me:

[How to align items in action bar to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454102/how-to-align-items-in-action-bar-to-the-left)
[Add custom layout to ActionBar with Gravity Left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994331/add-custom-layout-to-actionbar-with-gravity-left)
[Android API 21 Toolbar Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding/26495926#26495926)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amrut Bidri for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433409/android-lollipop-appcompat-actionbar-custom-view-doesnt-take-up-whole-screen-w), I found the solution:
(yet I still don't know why setting the gravity in the layout file didn't work)

```
    ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = (ActionBar.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```