# ActionBar Material - removing space to left of custom view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

I'm making a custom ActionBar for the first time. I was using the Theme.AppCompat.Light, but noticed that there is still space to the left of my custom view. 
I made a test app to analyze the effect of altering different ActionBar elements, here are the comparisons.
How can I remove that annoying space?

This is what I want!

theme: Theme.Holo.Light

[image]

This is what I'm getting with material theme, LOOK AT THAT ANNOYING SPACE!

theme: Theme.Material.Light

[image]

Here are with the other toggle buttons checked
[image]
[image]

Comment: Provide your layout file code please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

which app is

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: You've pointed me in the right direction, I'll return after implementing and seeing the results to follow up.

Comment: This worked great, this link is also useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding

Comment: Where do you place this? In the actionbar custom view's root layout ?

Comment: @patrickjason91 at the toolbar definition, where you define `android:layout_width` and ...

Comment: I placed those 2 lines in the root relative layout xml of my custom action toolbar and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are selecting DeviceDefaultTheme. You could use android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar for action bar.