# Toolbar adds extra space at its left

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using a custom toolbar in my app. Toolbar adds extra space at its left side. This is my Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/customActionBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titleBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/actionTitleText"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_22sp"
        android:padding="@dimen/size_12dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rightIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Can you please help?
it gives some margin from left of screen, but i have not given any margin attribute.
This is code to inflate that into activity:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        baseViewContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_content_view);
        viewController = new ViewController(this, baseViewContent);
        activity = this;

        // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.customActionBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Show us how you inflate that layout, and post the layout in which you inflate this (if any, for example the layout of the activity in which you are placing the toolbar).

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        baseViewContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_content_view);
        viewController = new ViewController(this, baseViewContent);
        activity = this;

        // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.customActionBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: So, post the content of `activity_main.xml` layout file.

Comment: This is main Activity XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_content_view"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/custom_actionbar">
    </include>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Post your parent layout!.

Comment: Possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/q/26455027/1384010

Answer (score 12):

Use

`app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`

to remove the extra space.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309500

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Comment: Well that is odd, because this is what fixed the problem for us when we had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For other people like me: It was the title in the toolbar that I was not seeing because it had the same color as background. You can remove it if you want with `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`