# How to align UI controls on a Custom Toolbar in Android xml

Tags: android, xamarin.android, toolbar

I'm creating a layout in Xamarin.Android and I'm working on a custom Toolbar with an image button a TextView and another label.  What I need to do is Make sure the imagebutton BackButton is left aligned all the way to the left of the parent Contain, the TextView is Center Aligned and the MenuButton Image Button is Right Aligned all the way to the right of the parent container.  Below you'll see my view in Design mode:

axml Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ToolBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/BackButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/RedButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back48x48"
        style="@style/back_button_text" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AppNameView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Just a Label ok" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/MenuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/RedButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu48x48"
        style="@style/menu_button_text" />
</Toolbar>
```

Just curious on the best way to do this.

The way this is getting called in another axml in the include below :

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:columnCount="3">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a RelativeLayout inside your Toolbar and do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ToolBar"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/BackButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/RedButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back48x48"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        style="@style/back_button_text" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AppNameView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Just a Label ok" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/MenuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/RedButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                      
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu48x48"
        style="@style/menu_button_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

The alignParentLeft property on the back button and alignParentRight on on the other button guarantee that they will stick to the left and right of the RelativeLayout containing them. It wasn't working before because the Toolbar isn't a RelativeLayout.

To remove the default margin for the Toolbar, follow the instructions on this question: [Android API 21 Toolbar Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding)

The properties contentInsetStart and contentInsetLeft must be zero.

Comment: Are you referring to the xml abover where I do the include?  Otherwise the parent object of the ImageButton is a tool bar

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, I will edit my answer right now

Comment: That didn't work.  That made a relative layout that was slightly smaller than the Toolbar in width and made the MenuButton ImageButton dissapear off the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the properties' names. It's android:layout_alignParentRight="true" and android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

Comment: Nope that still has a problem  Basically if you go to the design view it shows the relative layout ending at the button edges.  I'll post a pic.

Comment: Take a look at the blue border in the pic that is the relative layout

Comment: Just found this after a little bit of search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding I guess you have to set this contentInsetStart property to zero.

Comment: Ok So that others know can you update this answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Hey there, @HisnamewasRobertPaulson could you please accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but could't you just use layout_gravity insteadof relativelayout??

like:

```
  android:layout_gravity="right"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_gravity="left"
```

I write this, because if you want to add stuff to toolbar later in code, it would push the relative layout to the side, with all its content.... I think so at least!:)

Comment: No because everything Control wise is in the axml(outside of listeners or delegates).