# Android ActionBar Backbutton Default Padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am creating a custom `ActionBar` using a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageButton` to the left to **replace** it. I have downloaded the Back icon from google's website to use on the `ImageButton`

The problem is that I need to create a Back button to replace the original `ActionBar`'s Back Button, and I need it to be exactly identical to the original `ActionBar`'s back button.

**I am wondering what is the system's default padding for the Back button image?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think the default value of contentInset is 16 dp (left & right)

For more info: (search content inset in this) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/dimens_material.xml

[Android API 21 Toolbar Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding)

I hope this answers you question.

Answer (score 12):

You need to add following lines in the  declaration as below:

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

You may adjust the spacing by tweaking around the above data.

Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
  app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
  app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
  app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
  app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
  app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [Material Design spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar), the Toolbar icon padding is 16dp.

See "App bar icon top, bottom, left padding: 16dp"