# Navigation Icon's position in Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, toolbar

Want to change Navigation Icon Position to 8dp left.

I have attach the screenshot

- Black Colour line is the Current Position.
- Orange Colour line is the position where, I want my Navigation icon to be placed.

Things I have implemented so far are.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/arrow"/>
```

and

```
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Tried Both
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); & actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: with toolbar there is a default margin from left , I don't know exactly how much but there is . Try making this with normal views like Relative or Linear Layout

Comment: Thanks Vivek (: .. Well I am not looking for alternative solution because I am facing same issue in my other screens like with coordination layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding see this link then

Comment: Dude check my implemented so far code.. I have implemented that solution.

Comment: My main motive to share that link to show how much is the default padding in toolbar. And I also searched and I think creating custom toolbar is the only solution

Answer (score 3):

please try adding

```
        android:paddingLeft="-8dp"
```

or

```
        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
```

this will work.