# Align Toolbar title and SearchView with list content with avatars

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to follow the material guidelines and I aligned the Toolbar title with the avatar like the image below following the instructions of @ChrisBanes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26495926/2153926).

[image]

My issue now is that when the SearchView is activated, it's not aligned anymore as seen in the second image. (It was aligned before changing the inset)

[image]

Any ideas of how I can align both things instead of having to choose between one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `app:titleMarginStart="16dp"` instead of changing the contentInset. I have tested it only in a xhdpi phone, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align avatar with search-view then you need remove space of homeup button and search-view.

FYI: search view behavior is different in large size device so you can go with custom action-bar.

Comment: But how do I remove the space without miss-aligning the title?