# Toolbar extra left inset/padding

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having an issue with the Android v7 support toolbar. When I activate the home as up button and showing it (see Java code below), there is an extra padding for the content of the toolbar which is an Image view. I would like to remove the Imageview left extra padding.

I already tried the attributes, nothing changed:

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Notice that when I use these attributes without the home as up, it works and there is no padding.

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/toolbarBackground"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_photo"
                android:padding="0dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

JAVA:

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Result:
[image: Toolbar content extra left padding]

How could I solve my problem?

**Edit** This question is different from [Android API 21 Toolbar Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding) because in my case I need to conserve the home as up (back) button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

1. `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`

2.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_action_bar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

3.
Make your imageView padding or margin less than 0?
e.g. -16dp etc.

Comment: Hi umitems, yes I tried but no results

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: For the first solution, I tried but there isn't the HomeAsUp Button which one I want to conserve. I trie setting actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); but without success.

Comment: the solution was: app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"

Comment: Not working for CollapsebleToolbarLayout . Please Help me.