# Remove left space in title view xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigationbar, tabbedpage, titleview

I had an issue in removing the extra left space in title view as shown in the image below [please see the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6KYm.png)

Ps: I'm using tabbed page and that bar is the navigation title view.

Comment: That padding is in-built

Comment: I find the solution of using InsetPadding https://medium.com/@prateekrm/custom-navigation-bar-with-controltemplate-in-xamarin-forms-7f61e05ebc14 but without details so I have no idea how to deal with it

Comment: But nothing is impossible with custom renderers @Greggz

Comment: The link you sent does not work with custom renderers. It's just creating your own "navigation bar". Just follow the post directions

Comment: he just mentioned InsetPadding in one line but didn't show an example @Greggz

Comment: Nevermind that! Your solution starts when he says **Better Solution using ControlTemplate** , so again, just follow the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the xml below in your `Toolbar.xml` of Android part.

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

[image]

Do not forget to add the namespace of app in your `Toolbar.xaml`.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And check the code below, it need to be added in `MainActivity.cs`.

```
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

**Usage:**

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Repositories" />
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

[image]

Comment: thnx a lot u just saved my life( although I lost full 7 hours of searching)

Comment: Okay, seems to work now. I think it was just necessary to remove all bin and obj folders from PCL and android project.

Comment: Dosn't Work for me ... Any Idea why ? Here is my Toolbar.xml :
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    />`

Comment: Change `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.

Comment: Indeed !!! Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990741/how-to-remove-left-space-in-toolbar-and-above-and-under) with a detailled explanation of your proposal. The solution here above was not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without customizing the xml layout is for those who already created a `IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker` subclassing `ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker` :

```
        public override void SetAppearance(Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);

            toolbar.SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
        }
```

The native problem is discussed here:

[Toolbar extra left inset/padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097919/toolbar-extra-left-inset-padding)