# What is the default spacing between toolbar icons on android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Does anyone know what padding/margins are used to layout toolbar icons?  Is this info available in any on-line docs?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any margin between the icons in the `Toolbar`.

Each icon is `24dp` wide and tall, with a padding on each side of `12dp`

Read more in the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to material guidelines:

App bar height: 56dp

App bar left and right padding: 16dp

App bar icon top, bottom, left padding: 16dp

App bar title left padding: 72dp

App bar title bottom padding: 20dp

[image]

Source: https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

Answer (score 0):

The left inset is caused by Toolbar's contentInsetStart which by default is 16dp.

Change this to 72dp to align to the keyline.

Update for support library v24.0.0:

To match the Material Design spec there's an additional attribute contentInsetStartWithNavigation which by default is 16dp. Change this if you also have a navigation icon. [For more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding)

Comment: You just copy someones answer and post as yours ... I don't like it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  However, I'm still not clear on what spacing between toolbar icons is.  Any hints?

Comment: @bdristan In my asnwer you can see that there is no margin between the icons

Answer (score 0):

According to material design documents the default height of toolbar in Android phone is 56 dp, and the icons should have 16 dp padding on all sides.
So the height and width of toolbar icons are 24 dp.
Reference: [Material design docs](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)