# How to remove extra padding on top of toolbar in appbarlayout android

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My code works fine, but there is a extra padding on top of toolbar. It looks ugly when I slide the image upwards. I want to remove this padding. Please see the attached image. Appreciate the help.

[image]

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinateLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="app.com.date.design.drawer.NavigationDrawer">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
                android:layout_height="350dip"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/side_nav_bar" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:layout_height="56dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/backdrop"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you want to hide the status bar?

Comment: Have a look on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that try in you Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` or apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`