# Margin between SearchView and collapseIcon in toolbar

Tags: android, searchview

I'm trying to implement `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` with a `collapseIcon` on the `Toolbar`. Everything works fine i.e, the `SearchView` is working as expected but I'm unable to remove/ reduce the padding between the `SearchView` and `collapseIcon`, as visible in the attached screenshot.

Any ideas on how can I do that?

[image: SearchView]

I've tried :

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the `collapseIcon`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding

Comment: not relevant, I've already mentioned in the question that I've tried all that. Anyways, solved the issue.

Comment: @AshishRanjan how did you solve this (the leftMargin approach mentioned below does not work)?

Comment: did you try setting the insets mentioned in the question to zero? @Bootstrapper , if yes then something may have changed in the SearchView xml, you can try looking at the xml yourself. or maybe you did something wrong while implementing the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by looking at the xml file that's used by `SearchView`, so the padding can be removed/reduced by changing the `leftMargin` value:

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
```

for the following `LinearLayout` inside the `SearchView`:

```
LinearLayout searchEditFrame = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame);
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem can be solved by setting the `leftMargin = 0` in the layout parameters associated with the following `LinearLayout` in the `SearchView`:

(To get the layout parameters use the [`getLayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams()))

```
LinearLayout searchEditFrame = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame); // Get the Linear Layout 
// Get the associated LayoutParams and set leftMargin
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) searchEditFrame.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = 0;
```

Comment: And in case anyone stumbles onto this looking to edit other properties, the XML can be found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml