# Remove Android SearchView padding when expanded

Tags: android, padding, searchview, extra

I'm trying to implement SearchView in my Android application but there is an extra padding when expanding it.

The SearchView is integrated in the Menu and when the app launches, I have a search icon inside the Toolbar. When I click that search button, the SearchView expands but has an extra padding.

Here are some photos so you can understand the issue:

**This is the initial toolbar**
[image: Initial Toolbar]

**When I click the search icon, this is what I get**[image: Expanded Search]

I found one solution, to add a negative left padding (-16dp) to the SearchView:        `searchView.setPadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.search_view_minus), 0, 0, 0);`

Unfortunately, if I use this solution the search icon on the right side of the toolbar will be affected (somehow the SearchView gets over the search icon).

This is my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Cauta..."/>

</menu>
```

This is my toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Title"
    app:titleMarginStart="0dp"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" />
```

This is some custom style applied to the SearchView:

```
<style name="searchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <item name="queryHint">@string/search_hint</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp</item>
    <item name="voiceIcon">@drawable/ic_keyboard_voice_white_24dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Is there a proper solution to my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510337/margin-between-searchview-and-collapseicon-in-toolbar