# I want to align the icons accordingly in my android app in the top bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align the icons accordingly in my android app in the top bar my top bar has side menu on the left [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQdUZ.png)

It has some empty space after the side menu icon I want to fill that space by arranging the icons accordingly but I don't know how to do that

please help me to avoid that empty space and put the icon in that place

I have also attached image for better view

Thanks

Comment: please show your layout

Comment: if you can use toolbar then follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455027/android-api-21-toolbar-padding

Answer (score 0):

please try to create a custom layout for action bar & inflate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setlogo method in toolbar to fill the your desired space

```
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.yourlogo);
```

or simply set all icon inside your toolbar according to your requirement.
like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope this help!